# Get index of array at equal points

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Let's say you have an array of length 20. You want to access 3 equally spaced indices: 0, 9, 19.

How can you do this with any length of array and any number of sections?

I feel like there must be an elegant way of doing it, but the only way I can think of is finding the section size (`var len = 20 / (3 -1)`), iterating over the total number of sections (`for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { var row = data[len * i]; }`), and then subtracting one for non-zero indices.

Comment: An array of length 20 (in javascript) has no element at index 20.

Comment: oops, my mistake. ill fix it. thanks for catching that

Comment: Since many array lengths cannot be split into N equal pieces, you would have to describe how you want the fractional spots to be allocated.  Depending upon how you want that done, the algorithm could be simple or not as simple.

Comment: could you give me an answer based on my example of an array of length 20 and i need 3 indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (where `console.log` is used now you can call your array):

```
var amount = 3;
var total = 20;

var size = (total - 1) / (amount - 1);
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    console.log(Math.floor(size * i));
}
```

There isn't realy a more elegant solution.

Comment: just realized i was flooring the `size` instead of `size * i`. thanks a lot!!

Comment: That was also my first approach. No problem.